# How to know if the mouse click is over a graphics image java

Tags: java, image, canvas, graphics, draw

I wanted to know if it is possible to know if when I left click my canvas there is an image icon under it, this is the code that must be able to hand that case:

```
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
    if (!labelSelected){

    // This is called by the system when the user presses the mouse button.
    // Record the location at which the mouse was pressed.  This location
    // is one endpoint of the line that will be drawn when the mouse is
    // released.  This method is part of the MouseLister interface.
    startX = evt.getX();
    startY = evt.getY();
    prevX = startX;
    prevY = startY;
    dragging = true;
    Random ran = new Random();
    int x = ran.nextInt(10);
    currentColorIndex = x;
    gc = getGraphics();  // Get a graphics context for use while drawing.
    gc.setColor(colorList[currentColorIndex]);
    gc.setXORMode(getBackground());
    gc.drawLine(startX, startY, prevX, prevY);
    }
}
```

but before drawing my line I want to make sure that the mouse is pressed over an graphics image, something like if (evt.getsource() == "Graphics ICON") or something like that.

Comment: How do you know where the icon is drawn?

Comment: I select an icon click somewhere on the canvas and then it is drew on the canvas, after that I must join let's say 2 different icons with a line so I thought of that, when I click the system checks that the click is over an image so that it let's you begin the line

Comment: So, you know where the icon image is?  How is this maintained?

Comment: Oh, by the way, NEVER use `getGraphics()` this is not how custom painting is done

Comment: Yes technically, I also could have an array with each image with it's x and y and when I make click iterate over the array to know if there is something on that position...

Comment: Why not use a clickable component?

Comment: The only way you're going to know if something exists at a specific location is if you are recording it.  The only other choice (and it's not pretty), would be to render the component to an off screen image and scan through the pixels...I know which I would prefer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check with the position of the image, for eg. if Image position is (X=100, Y=100) and width and height is 100. Then you can check with the current position of the cursor. And get the X position, Y position, width and height from the `ImageIcon` object. Like -

```
// imgX has the position of Image in X direction
// imgY has the position of Image in Y direction
// imgW has the width of image
// imgH has the height of image
```

So now I can check with-

```
if((startX <= imgX+imgW && startX >= imgX) && (startY <= imgY+imgH && startY >= imgH))
{
   //On the image
}
else
{
  //Out side of the image
}
```